# can't get the right text when webscraping a webpage (with Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is an example of the variable 'extract', when i execute my python code:
**<a href "https://www.dekrantenkoppen.be/detail/1520347/Vulkaanuitbarsting-en-aardbevingen-dichtbij-de-hoofdstad-van-IJsland.html" rel="dofollow" title="In het zuidwesten van IJsland is de vulkaan Fagradalsfjall uitgebarsten. Dat heeft de meteorologische dienst van het land laten weten. De uitbarsting is vooralsnog beperkt, maar er zijn wel twee grote lavastromen. De voorbije weken was IJsland al opgeschrikt door tienduizenden aardbevingen. In de loop van de dag is de kracht van de uitbarsting afgenomen.">Vulkaanuitbarsting en aardbevingen dichtbij de hoofdstad van IJsland**

W^hen i execute my code, i now get the text *'Vulkaanuitbarsting en aardbevingen dichtbij de hoofdstad van IJsland'*
What i really wanted is the part after 'title=', so this text: *'In het zuidwesten van IJsland is de vulkaan Fagradalsfjall uitgebarsten. Dat heeft de meteorologische dienst van het land laten weten. De uitbarsting is vooralsnog beperkt, maar er zijn wel twee grote lavastromen. De voorbije weken was IJsland al opgeschrikt door tienduizenden aardbevingen. In de loop van de dag is de kracht van de uitbarsting afgenomen.'*

I'm new in this section, and i find it very difficult to understand. Can someone give me a good direction?

See my code at this moment.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.dekrantenkoppen.be/full/de_redactie'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
#print(soup)

content=''
rows = soup.find_all('a')
tel=0
for row in rows:
    if tel != 0:
        #'tel' is only used to skip the first returned result. The first resultline is something that i don't need. I only need all the text after every 'title ='

        print(row)
        extract=row.get_text()
        print('')
        print(extract)
        content=content+extract+'\n'

    
    if tel == 10:
        #a loop of max 10 times gives me enough information, i only need the first 10 articles
        break
    else:
        tel=tel+1
        
#show me the result-text of the crawling
print('')
print('RESULT TEXT OF THE FIRST 10 ARTICLES:')
print(content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the title attribute. From the description the following use of nth-child will get you the first 10 descriptions. I also needed 'lxml' parser. `pip3 install lxml` if not installed.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.dekrantenkoppen.be/full/de_redactie'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
print([i['title'] for i in soup.select('li:nth-child(-n+10) > a:nth-child(2)')])
```

---

CSS:

```
li:nth-child(-n+10) > a:nth-child(2)
```

This asks for the first 10 `li` elements with at least two `a` tag children, and selects for the second `a` tag in each case. The `>` is a child combinator specifying that what is on the right must be a child of what is on the left.

---

Read about:

1. [:nth-child ranges](http://nthmaster.com/)
2. [Child combinators, pseudo class selectors and type selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

---

Additional request for `for loop` with published date time info:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.dekrantenkoppen.be/full/de_redactie'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

for i in soup.select('li:nth-child(-n+10) > a:nth-child(2)'):
    print(i.parent['title'])
    print(i.parent.a.text.strip())
    print(i['title'])
    print()
```

Comment: Also tried this solution, and this also works fine!  Although i will have to digg in the details, this is more difficult for a newby to understand. Thanks QHarr for this solution.

Comment: I added a little extra description for you.

Comment: Hi QHarr, last question, because it's to difficult for me to understand. I want the solution you gave me earlier, extended with the date it was published (e.g. <li title='4 - 2021-03-22 19:43:02'>). But i want it in a SIMPLE LOOP, where for each instance of the loop, i can get the title of the article in an outputfield1 and the timestamp it was published in an outputfield2? How do i do this for the website: https://www.dekrantenkoppen.be/full/de_redactie?

Comment: Wow, exactly what i wanted, you made my day! Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should try to modify your code as follows:

```
...
for row in rows:
    if tel != 0:
        print(row)
        extract=row["title"]
        content=content+extract.replace("Meer informatie", "")+'\n'
...
```

Comment: Tried this bit and YES, it works exactly the way i wanted it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Quick look at what you're doing, simply replace `get_text()` with `.get('title')`, that should work:

```py
>>> data = '''<a href "https://www.dekrantenkoppen.be/detail/1520347/Vulkaanuitbarsting-en-aardbevingen-dichtbij-de-hoofdstad-van-IJsland.html" rel="dofollow" title="In het zuidwesten van IJsland is de vulkaan Fagradalsfjall uitgebarsten. Dat heeft de meteorologische dienst van het land laten weten. De uitbarsting is vooralsnog beperkt, maar er zijn wel twee grote lavastromen. De voorbije weken was IJsland al opgeschrikt door tienduizenden aardbevingen. In de loop van de dag is de kracht van de uitbarsting afgenomen.">Vulkaanuitbarsting en aardbevingen dichtbij de hoofdstad van IJsland'''
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> soup.find('a').get('title')
'In het zuidwesten van IJsland is de vulkaan Fagradalsfjall uitgebarsten. Dat heeft de meteorologische dienst van het land laten weten. De uitbarsting is vooralsnog beperkt, maar er zijn wel twee grote lavastromen. De voorbije weken was IJsland al opgeschrikt door tienduizenden aardbevingen. In de loop van de dag is de kracht van de uitbarsting afgenomen.'
```